# Can someone help explain the output of these 2 threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Join1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.print("EnterValue:");
                try {
                    System.in.read();
                } catch (Exception ex) {}
                System.out.println("Thread Finished.");
            }
        };
        System.out.println("Starting Thread");
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Joining");
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
        System.out.println("Main Finished.");
    }
}
```

Output

Starting Thread

Joining

Enter Value:

Thread Finished

Main Finished

```
public class Join2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("EnterValue:");
                    try {
                        System.in.read();
                    } // thread blocked
                    catch (Exception ex) {}
                    System.out.println("Thread Finished.");
                }
            };

            System.out.println("Starting Thread");
            t.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            System.out.println("No Join");
            System.out.println("Main Finished.");
        }
    }
```

Output

Starting Thread

Enter Value:

No Join

Main Finished

3 (input)

Thread Finished

I don't understand the order of some of this output. Eg in Join2, why does it output the finished lines in main before you get to enter your value?

Comment: What stops `main` from finishing in example 2?

Comment: Because threads don't block the main program, they are on separate threads which aren't blocking.

Comment: Also, I would highly advise against swallowing exceptions (`catch (Exception ex) {}`).  you should, at minimum, do `ex.printStackTrace()`.  That may even be contributing to your issue (we have no way of knowing).

Comment: This is from a teachers notes. I just want to know why the order of the output is as it is

Comment: @JohnBanter I'd advise you to do some research on what threads are and how they work. I told you why in my last comment. Think of each thread as it's own independent sub-program, the threads you made do not stop the main thread from finishing. Because of that it will finish on the main thread and be waiting for input on the ones you created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference in the two examples given is the method invoked after the start of the thread with `t.start()`

Join1.java calls `Thread.join()` which, from the docs, says it "Waits for this thread to die". Thus only when the run method of the thread is finished (after the `System.in.read()` finishes) does the "Main Finished." print"

Join2.java calls `Thread.sleep(2000)` which pauses the thread for 2000 milliseconds. Try commenting that line out and seeing the result. Additionally, notice that the program did not quit after it prints "Main Finished." The thread is still waiting for input.

TLDR;

`Thread.join()` makes main pause until that thread finishes.

`Thread.sleep(2000)` only pauses main for 2 seconds before continuing, the other thread continues to run.

Comment: Re, "...pauses the thread" (or "blocks the thread," or "sleeps (sic.) the thread," etc.)  Some of those words are stumbling blocks for newbies who haven't quite grasped the concepts.  Sometimes, they get it more quickly if you say, "`Thread.sleep(2000)` _does nothing_ but wait for two seconds."  or "`t.join()` _does nothing_ but wait for thread `t` to finish."  That latter one is especially helpful because a lot of newbies get the mistaken idea from somewhere that `t.join()` does _something_ to thread `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of threads as concurrent executions. By the time your main return from .start(), the new thread is free to proceed, ok. But in the Join2, you are not telling the main thread to wait for the thread t to be finished. So in 2 seconds it moves past the sleep.